# autocomplete search key specify

Tags: user-interface, user-input, ace-editor

By default autocomplete in ace editor picks up value for search and value for substituting in the text field. Can we specify a name for search and value for substitution? Any help is appreciated.

eg for completor

```
    var completer = {
        getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
            var f = [
                {'value': '2', 'name': 'two'},
                {'value': '3', 'name': 'three'},
                {'value': 'four', 'name': '4'}
            ];
            callback(null, f);
        }
    };
```

In this example, the only value is used for the search. I want to show customers a verbose text during popup but when he/she hits select value should be substituted.

Comment: You want to show the user an autosuggestion list and then once the user clicks on any of the items you want to substitute the word with another word right?

Comment: yes. for eg if the user clicks on two then 2 will be substituted.

Comment: you mean like `{'value': 'two', 'name': '2'}` but done automatically and vice versa?